# How to display wordpress Editor Items for non Logged in User in frontend?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, tinymce

Im using the `AccessPress Anonymous Post` plugin to have the tiny mce editor in the frontend of the wordpress page. Now i would like to let all of the user post emoticons as well. But the icon of the emoticons plugin only shows up in the editor when the user is admin, while some other editor plugins also works for non logged in user.

[image: when im logged in]

The image below shows the editor when im not logged in, but i would need it like above.

[image: when im not logged]

How can i tell the emoticon plugin to show up and work in any case in the editor?
Where is the hook in wordpress code to achieve this?

thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent hours faffing about with a similar issue and settled on using a plugin to amend the user roles:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/